# Use resource font directly in VB.net/C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, fonts, resources

How to use resource font directly without saving font in local file system for standalone application[desktop application] in VB.net/C#?

Comment: @SamSol: there's no such thing as CS.NET. Where did you ever hear of that? The language is just "C#".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's possible, you'll need to use the PrivateFontCollection.AddMemoryFont() method.  For example, I added a font file named "test.ttf" as a resource and used it like this:

```
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    private static PrivateFontCollection myFonts;
    private static IntPtr fontBuffer;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (myFonts == null) {
            myFonts = new PrivateFontCollection();
            byte[] font = Properties.Resources.test;
            fontBuffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(font.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(font, 0, fontBuffer, font.Length);
            myFonts.AddMemoryFont(fontBuffer, font.Length);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
        FontFamily fam = myFonts.Families[0];
        using (Font fnt = new Font(fam, 16)) {
            TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "Private font", fnt, Point.Empty, Color.Black);
            //e.Graphics.DrawString("Private font", fnt, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Do note that the `fontBuffer` variable is *static* intentionally.  Memory management is difficult when you use AddMemoryFont(), the memory needs to remain valid as long as the font can be used and the PrivateFontCollection is not yet disposed.  Be sure not to call Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem() if you don't have that guarantee, it is a *very* common bug that causes very hard to diagnose text corruption.  You only get an AccessViolationException when you are lucky.  Keeping it valid for the life of the program is the simple solution.

Comment: @HansPassant : what if the font file i want to add is having '.bin' extension instead of '.ttf'

Comment: I needed to use PInvoke before things worked.  The function [`AddFontMemResourceEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183325(v=vs.85).aspx) had to be used... perhaps because `PrivateFontCollection.AddMemoryFont()` expects the font to be in system memory.  I also wonder if this has anything to do with the fact that I was changing the font of a textbox, rather than explicit rendering with the font.  (Yet using `PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile()` still worked without the PInvoke function).

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about Packaging fonts with application. if Yes. 
check out this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753303.aspx