# Using custom fonts in my winform labels

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I wonder if its possible to use a custom font for my form labels without installing it on the users machine? I would like to display a text using a font I have rights to, but its not installed on the potencial user machine.

Are there any solutions for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the extract (using [PrivateFontCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.aspx)):

```
Dim pfc As New PrivateFontCollection()
pfc.AddFontFile("C:\Path To\PALETX3.ttf")
label1.Font = New Font(pfc.Families(0), 16, FontStyle.Regular)
```

Converted from here: [Load And Use Custom Font Without Installing It](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107377/Load-And-Use-Custom-Font-Without-Installing-It).

Also check this: [Embedding/deploying custom font in .NET app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007805/embedding-deploying-custom-font-in-net-app)

Comment: A potencial user wont have this font downloaded so I could use a path to load it I think. Is there a posibility to load a font using the resources?

Comment: @Scott: Yes, it is possible, see this link: [Use resource font directly in VB.net/C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928383/use-resource-font-directly-in-vb-net-c).

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in Top of your Code

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
```

Add this code on Form1_Load() to change the Lablel1.Font

```
Dim customfont As PrivateFontCollection = New PrivateFontCollection
customfont.AddFontFile("C:\maven.ttf")
Label1.Font = New Font(customfont.Families(0), 10)
```

Tested on Visual Basic 2010 Enterprises Edition